# Determine in how many ways the amount of 50 can be paid by bank notes of 1, 2, 5, 10, and 20

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> Determine in how many ways the amount of 50 can be paid by bank notes of 1, 2, 5, 10, and 20

I have used the generating function that

$G(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^5}\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}\frac{1}{1-x^{20}}$

and $G(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x^2}\frac{(1+x^5)(1+x^{10)}}{(1-x^{20})^3}$, and then i expand it with two binomial series which product together, and find the answer 450

I want to know whether the answer is correct, and find a easy way to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: The answer 450 is correct. (*Copy [coin change problem c++ code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/) into an [online c++ compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler).*)

Comment: 450 is correct, but your second expression is not correct. It should be (1 + x) (1 + x^5) (1 + x^10)^2/((1 - x^2)^2 (1 - x^20)^3). Try finding the series for 1/((1 - x^2)^2 (1 - x^20)^3).